# Wordpress Nonce Verification Fails when Posting to a non-Wordpress Custom PHP File

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a non-Wordpress custom PHP file that I am trying to submit a Wordpress form to that is located within my Wordpress plugins folder.

In my Wordpress form, I have included this line between the form tags:

```
<?php wp_nonce_field('nonce'); ?>
```

And in the custom PHP file I have the following code:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php");
$retrieved_nonce = $_POST['_wpnonce'];
if (wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce, 'nonce') {
    echo "Validation passed!";
} else {
    echo "Validation failed.";
}
```

Everytime I submit the form the validation fails. Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The non-Wordpress way that I got this to work can be found [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753/).